# ng-checked causing invalid form

Tags: angularjs

Is this by design? I have a form where I set ng-checked on a bunch of checkboxes/radio buttons. The form is invalid initially until I manually uncheck and check the checkboxes/radios. I know I can set the values initially in my controller but I am trying to avoid it.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <form name="someForm" ng-submit="someForm.$valid" novalidate>
   <input type="checkbox" name="someCheckbox" ng-model="someCheckbox" 
                                      ng-checked="true" required value="c">checkbox
   <input type="radio" name="someRadio" ng-model="someRadio" 
                                     ng-checked="true" required value="r"> radio 1
   <input type="radio" name="someRadio" ng-model="someRadio" required value="h">radio 2

   <input type="submit">
 </form>

 <div ng-show="someForm.someCheckbox.$error.required">somecheckbox is required</div>
 <div ng-show="someForm.someRadio.$error.required">someradio is required</div>
</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SahfQSggiwJixgU48yWI?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad, I've already answered this question, but can't find it again :-(

copied from angular source code :

```
var ngAttributeAliasDirectives = {};
// boolean attrs are evaluated
forEach(BOOLEAN_ATTR, function(propName, attrName) {
// binding to multiple is not supported
if (propName == "multiple") return;
function defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr) {
scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function ngBooleanAttrWatchAction(value) {
attr.$set(attrName, !!value);
});
}
var normalized = directiveNormalize('ng-' + attrName);
var linkFn = defaultLinkFn;
if (propName === 'checked') {
linkFn = function(scope, element, attr) {
// ensuring ngChecked doesn't interfere with ngModel when both are set on the same input
if (attr.ngModel !== attr[normalized]) {
defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr);
}
};
}
ngAttributeAliasDirectives[normalized] = function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
priority: 100,
link: linkFn
};
};
});
```

ng-checked and ng-model are not supposed to work together.

If you want a default startup configuration for your checkboxes, you should initialize your ng-model inside your controller :

```
$scope.somecheckbox = true;
```

Comment: I figured as much. Was trying to avoid initializing a bunch of fields in my controller

Answer (score 3):

ngModel and ngChecked are not meant to be used together.

ngChecked is expecting an expression, so by saying ng-checked="true", you're basically saying that the checkbox or radio button will always be checked by default.

Now how to set default value of checkbox and radio button :-

```
$scope.someCheckbox=true;
$scope.someRadio="someRadio";<-here $scope.someRadio must be equal to value="someRadio" on one of the radio button.
```

So ng-checked="true" doesn't validate the model therefore it will not validate your form.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vjFzbSZutcBZcnoa9XhU?p=info)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your *someCheckbox* and *someRadio* in your *MainCtrl* declaration.

In your *app.js*, where you declare your controller:

```
yourApp.controller('MainCtrl', ...);
```

add the second parameter to initialize the variables of the controller:

```
yourApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.someCheckbox = true;
  $scope.someRadio = true;
}]);
```

Finally, remove the *ng-checked* directive since the *ng-model* will handle this.